# Sumar varios <span> y mostrarlos al presionar un boton

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

ahora bien ya me realiza el calculo y me aparece en cada etiqueta span, mi inquietud es como se puede realizar la suma de todos los span al presionar el boton de clase btnPedir aqui esta mi html

```html
 <thead>
                                    <th>NOMBRE</th>
                                    <th>IMAGEN</th>
                                    <th>COSTO</th>
                                    <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                                    <th>PRECIO</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <?php while ($usuarios = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo"{$usuarios["NOMBRE"]}" ?></td>
                                            <td><img src="<?php echo"{$usuarios["IMAGEN"]}" ?>" width="80px" class="img-responsive"></td>
                                            <td><input value="<?php echo"{$usuarios["COSTO"]}" ?>" id="costo" disabled style="width: 25%"></td>
                                            <td><input type="number" min="0" class="input-sm" id="cantidad" style="width: 25%"></td>
                                            <td><span id="resp"></span></td>
                                            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btnCalcula">Agregar</button></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    <?php } ?>
                                </table>
<button class="btnPedir">Agregar</button>
```

aqui esta mi JS

```
<script>       
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.btnCalcula');


        allButtons.forEach(function (btn, index) {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

                var thisCells = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.cells;
                var valOne = thisCells[2].children[0].value;
                var valTwo = thisCells[3].children[0].value;
                var thisSpan = thisCells[4].children[0];
                var total = parseFloat(valOne) * parseFloat(valTwo);
        var aux += total;
        var txtSuma = aux;
        //quiero que la suma se active al presionar el boton pedir
                var txtSpan = `${total} $`;
                thisSpan.textContent = txtSpan;

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te muestro aquí una aproximación interesante para calcular el total. Se trata de lo siguiente:

- Poner en el `span` de cada fila un atributo data `subtotal`, para ir registrando en dicho atributo el estado actual de cada fila. Dicho atributo debe crearse con un valor `0` por defecto, el cual se irá cambiando dinámicamente. El elemento quedaría así: `<span data-subtotal="0">` en cada fila. Estos atributos no son visibles en la página, por lo que son de suma utilidad para manejar datos internos.
- Crear una función `getTotal` que será llamada cada vez que se pulse el botón `Calcular Total`. Esa función seleccionará todos los `span` que tienen el atributo `data-subtotal` y sumará los valores que hay en esos atributos.
- Cada vez que se agregue un valor en una fila, el span de esa fila guardará el total calculado para esa fila con `thisSpan.dataset.subtotal = total;` y se actualizará el contenedor general (fondo verde) llamando también a la función `getTotal`.

Esta lógica permite mantener el total general actualizado siempre.

He puesto comentarios a lo largo del código, para que se comprenda lo que ocurre en cada momento.

Espero te sirva.

```js
var btnTotal = document.getElementById('btnTotal');
btnTotal.onclick = getTotal;

/*
  Esta función es invocada siempre que se necesite calcular el total
  sea desde el botón Calcula Total,
  sea desde el botón que agrega nuevos valores en cada fila
*/
function getTotal() {
  /*
    Buscamos el atributo data-valor de cada span
  */
  var allSubTotal = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-subtotal]');
  var totalGlobal = 0;
  /*
    Leemos los valores en cada data-valor y lo sumamos a totalGlobal
  */
  allSubTotal.forEach(function(el) {
    var subTotal = parseInt(el.dataset.subtotal);
    totalGlobal += subTotal;
  });
  console.log(`TOTAL GENERAL: ${totalGlobal}`); //prueba
  /*
    Devolvemos el valor a quien llamó la función
  */
  return totalGlobal;
}


/*
  --- LÓGICA PARA LAS FILAS ---
  Seleccionamos todos los botones con la clase btnCalcula
*/
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.btnCalcula');

/*
  A todos esos botones le aplicamos la misma función
  Cualquiera de ellos que sea clickeado lanzará
  este bloque de código....
*/
allButtons.forEach(function(btn, index) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    /*
      Ahora vamos a recuperar las celdas de la fila
      donde se encuentra el botón para sacar los valores
      y para cambiar el texto del span
    */
    var thisCells = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.cells;
    var valOne = thisCells[0].children[0].value;
    var valTwo = thisCells[1].children[0].value;
    var thisSpan = thisCells[2].children[0];
    var total = parseInt(valOne) * parseInt(valTwo);
    var txtSpan = `El total de tu compra es: ${total}$`;
    thisSpan.textContent = txtSpan;
    /*
      Actualizamos el atributo data-subtotal del span
    */
    thisSpan.dataset.subtotal = total;
    var cellTotal = document.getElementById('total');
    /*
      Invocamos a getTotal para actualizar el contenedor verde
    */
    cellTotal.textContent = getTotal();
  });
});
```

```css
#total {
  background-color: #C8E6C9;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="10" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number"></td>
    <td><span data-subtotal="0"></span></td>
    <td><button class="btnCalcula">Calcula</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="5" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number"></td>
    <td><span data-subtotal="0"></span></td>
    <td><button class="btnCalcula">Calcula</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL:</td>
    <td id="total"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btnTotal">Calcula Total</button>
```